# how to make Tensorflow2.2 access GPU on databricks GPU cluster

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, databricks

My question is relevant to my previous question. [how to enable GPU visible for ML runtime environment on databricks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62489900/how-to-enable-gpu-visible-for-ml-runtime-environment-on-databricks)

```
 6.6 ML, spark 2.4.5, GPU, Scala 2.11  
 Keras version : 2.2.5

 nvidia-smi
 NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00    Driver Version: 440.64.00    CUDA Version: 10.2
```

I created a new post because I need to post more  code.

I have installed Tensorflow2.2 on databricks by running the shell script: https://docs.databricks.com/applications/deep-learning/single-node-training/tensorflow.html#install-tensorflow-22-on-databricks-runtime-66-ml&language-GPU

I am trying to run some Tensorflow (2.2) code on databricks GPU cluster (p2.xlarge).

The python3 code is at :

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu
```

My code run from databricks notebook:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
# 0 

import tensorflow as tf
print("Tensorflow version : {}".format(tf.__version__))
print("Num XLA_GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('XLA_GPU')))
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
print("phy devices Available: ", tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices())

# Tensorflow version : 2.2.0
# Num XLA_GPUs Available:  1
# Num GPUs Available:  0
# phy devices Available:  [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), 
# PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_CPU:0', device_type='XLA_CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU')]

# use gpu https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

 # Create some tensors
 a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
 b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
 c = tf.matmul(a, b)

 print(c)
```

the output from the above code:

```
tf.Tensor([[22. 28.][49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

But, it only run on CPU not on GPU.

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('XLA_GPU')
 
phy_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices()
print(phy_devices)

 visible_devices = tf.config.get_visible_devices()
 print('visible_devices : ' + str(visible_devices))

 if not gpus:
    print('no gpus')
 else:
    print(gpus)
    print(gpus[0])
    # Restrict TensorFlow to only use the first GPU
try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(gpus[0], 'XLA_GPU') # exception poped here !!!
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('XLA_GPU')
    print('logical_gpus : ' + str(logical_gpus))
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPU")
 except RuntimeError as e:
   # Visible devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
   print(e)
```

output:

```
visible_devices : [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')][PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU')]
PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU')
Visible devices cannot be modified after being initialized
```

How to make tensorflow access GPU ?

Comment: I have same problem